# Can't access the cherokee admin - stuck loading

Tags: cherokee

I've installed Cherokee on a CentOS 6.3 VM through EPEL repo.

If I open `http://localhost` in elinks (sorry no gui) I can see the "Powered by Cherokee" page fine.

I've then launched the cherokee-admin process and open `http://localhost:9090` in elinks.

I'm being asked the login and passsword, which I enter, but then nothing happens. It gets stuck loading.

I've tried the ssh tunnel technique to load it in a fancier browser like chrome in case that was the problem but it's the same scenario, I get the popup asking me for the username and password but then the browser gets stuck loading.

On a few occasions, Chrome shows a "504 Gateway Timeout" message but not always. If I refresh when that happens then it gets stuck again.

What am I missing here?

If I let chrome run long enough I get this error message:

```
503 Service Unavailable

------------------------

Cherokee web server 1.2.101 (UNIX), Port 9090
```

I've got Python 2.6.6

This is the output when I start `cherokee-admin -x -b`

```
Cherokee Web Server 1.2.101 (Feb 21 2012): Listening on port ALL:9090, TLS
disabled, IPv6 enabled, using epoll, 4096 fds system limit, max. 2041
connections, single thread

Login:
  User:              admin
  One-time Password: 2nEKQfD3RqLbKJ5a

Web Interface:
  URL:               http://localhost:9090/
```

When I open up the admin in a browser the cherokee-admin displays this:

```
DEBUG: SIGUSR1 invokes the console..
       SIGUSR2 prints a backtrace..
Server 1.2.101 running.. PID=3570 Port=4000
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why (as in, I really don't know) but if I run cherokee-admin with `-t` switch then it loads fine.

The `-t` switch is described as

```
-t, --internal-unix
```

> ```
> By default, cherokee-admin uses TCP for internal communications. 
> This parameter specifies that a Unix domain socket should be used instead. 
> The default behavior is the safest one, so this parameter should rarely by used.
> ```

So that fixes the problem I guess.

Comment: I had to use this for my Cherokee 1.2.104 on FreeBSD 9 too.  Thanks for the suggestion.